# Moq: Change Setup Returns Generic method to deal with Asynchronous Parameter

Tags: c#, asynchronous, moq

I have a Moq setup statement that looks like this with a conditional/generic Returns statement based on the enum value passed in:

```
        MyLogic.Setup(m => m.MyLogicMethod(It.IsAny<MyEnum>()))
                                     .Returns<MyEnum>((x) =>
                                     {
                                         switch (x)
                                         {
                                             case MyEnum.Enum1: return "stringval1";
                                             case MyEnum.Enum2: return "stringval2";
                                             case MyEnum.Enum3: return "stringval3";
                                             case MyEnum.Enum4: return "stringval4";
                                             case MyEnum.Enum5: return "stringval5";
                                             default: return string.Empty;
                                         }
                                     });
```

I have now changed the method being tested to be async (returning `Task<string>`). Moq does not offer a generic ReturnsAsync, so how can I change the above Setup statement to work with an asynchronous method?

```
        MyLogic.Setup(m => m.MyLogicMethodAsync(It.IsAny<MyEnum>()))
                                     .Returns????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `ReturnAsync`, you can keep your return method, just return a `Task<>`.

```
MyLogic.Setup(m => m.MyLogicMethod(It.IsAny<MyEnum>()))
                                 .Returns<MyEnum>((x) =>
                                 {
                                     string returnValue = null;
                                     switch (x)
                                     {
                                         case MyEnum.Enum1: returnValue = "stringval1";
                                         case MyEnum.Enum2: returnValue = "stringval2";
                                         case MyEnum.Enum3: returnValue = "stringval3";
                                         case MyEnum.Enum4: returnValue = "stringval4";
                                         case MyEnum.Enum5: returnValue = "stringval5";
                                         default: returnValue = string.Empty;
                                     }

                                     return Task.FromResult(returnValue);
                                 });
```

Comment: It now needs 'break's between the cases but yep, Task.FromResult works thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Moq does not offer a generic ReturnsAsync,

Moq does offer a generic `ReturnsAsync`.

```
//
// Summary:
//     Specifies a function that will calculate the value to return from the asynchronous
//     method.
//
// Parameters:
//   mock:
//     Returns verb which represents the mocked type and the task of return type
//
//   valueFunction:
//     The function that will calculate the return value.
//
// Type parameters:
//   TMock:
//     Mocked type.
//
//   TResult:
//     Type of the return value.
public static IReturnsResult<TMock> ReturnsAsync<TMock, TResult>(this IReturns<TMock, Task<TResult>> mock, Func<TResult> valueFunction) where TMock : class;
```

***Assembly Moq, Version = 4.15.0.0***

Move your generic argument into the delegate so that the it can be implied by the generic method.

```
MyLogic
    .Setup(m => m.MyLogicMethodAsync(It.IsAny<MyEnum>()))
    .ReturnsAsync((MyEnum x) => {
         switch (x) {
             case MyEnum.Enum1: return "stringval1";
             case MyEnum.Enum2: return "stringval2";
             case MyEnum.Enum3: return "stringval3";
             case MyEnum.Enum4: return "stringval4";
             case MyEnum.Enum5: return "stringval5";
             default: return string.Empty;
         }
     });
```